# RAM based CDN Implementation

Tags: cdn, ram

I am looking to launch a new project and wanted to keep the latency as low as possible as well as load times.

i have been doing some research into CDN's and it seems like SSD CDN's are a good direction to go down but I have read that RAM based CDN's are even quicker!

I cannot find anyone who has done this, do you know anyone or how to implement this?

Comment: Off topic, go to serverfault instead :)

Comment: Store file data in main memory using something like memcache.

Comment: Modern operating systems will cache files in RAM anyway, so there may not be much of a difference in practice. This is not really a productive or answerable question for SO though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using RAM for a CDN might work for really small scale systems, but not for globe spanning CDN's. Because RAM is volatile and needs energy to maintain the data. And energy costs...

There are solutions on the market, like non-volatile PRAM/PCRAM or in development, like RRAM (resistive-RAM), but not in the dimensions suiteable for a CDN. From my point of view, the tech is not there, yet. The current market (2014) is using SSD tech to speed things up. So if you want to start a project, focus on SSD.

You might want to read about CDN tech used at Google, Akamai, Edgecast, Fastly just to name a few.